# Stacking Uncertainty Over Time

Tags: probability, discrete-calculus

I am currently working on a probabilistic model of a known linear system.  It is desired to estimate the value of a system process at discrete time steps.

Each time step could be described as follows:

```
y[k] = y[k-1] + V/L*dT
```

Parameter dT is fixed.

Both "V" and "L" parameters are constant but do have a bounded tolerance limit - say +/- dV and +/-dL.

Assume continuous uniform distribution - that is, the probability of "V" in range of "V0-dV" to "V0+dV" is 1/(2 dV).

If y[k-1] is 0 (known value), what is the range of y[k] and y[k+1]?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a problem belonging to the tag "probability" because you did not define the probabilities belonging to the different cases.

For example, let the probabilities belonging to $\pm dV$ and $\pm dL$ be all $\frac12$ and let these quantities be independent.

Now, to answer the question: There are four possibilities for the sign of $dV $ and $dL $: $++,+-,-+,++$ all these occur with probability $\frac 14$. The possible outcomes for
$$y (k)=\begin{cases}
\frac {dV}{dL}\text { with probability }\frac12\\
-\frac {dV}{dL}\text { with probability }\frac12
\end {cases}.$$

The range is given then.

For $k+1$ we have

$$y (k+1)=\begin{cases}
\frac {dV}{dL}+\frac {dV}{dL}\text { with probability }\frac14\\
\frac {dV}{dL}-\frac {dV}{dL}\text { with probability }\frac14
\end {cases}$$

and

$$y (k+1)=\begin{cases}
-\frac {dV}{dL}+\frac {dV}{dL}\text { with probability }\frac14\\
-\frac {dV}{dL}-\frac {dV}{dL}\text { with probability }\frac14
\end {cases}.$$

The range can be seen now.

Comment: Hi Zoli, thank you for your answer.  I am sorry about not being clear.  The measured values are bounded but could be located anywhere between V0+/- dV (L0 +/- dL) with continuous uniform distribution.

Comment: @SunnyBoyNY: I set up an example to which a non-continuous distribution belongs. If you set the joint distribution of the incremental values then I will try to compute the distribution of $y(k)$ and $y(k+1)$.